# Need Help On Code, All Results Are Coming Back False, when 2 should be true

Tags: python

So basically, I need to write a code for the luhn algorithm, but i need to have at least 5 functions

I have written a code to do this, yet I am receiving False results where they should be true.  For example, I know that the second and the fourth data pieces in the data file are true for this algorithm, yet all of my outputs are false.  Can you help me figure out where I've gone wrong?

This is the code:

```
def CheckLength(numb):
    if len(numb)>12 and len(numb)<17:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def CheckType(numb):
    if numb[0]=='4':
        return 'Visa'
    elif numb[0]=='5':
        return 'MasterCard'
    elif numb[0]=='6':
        return 'Discover'
    elif numb[0:2]=='37':
        return 'American Express'
    else:
        return 'Invalid Entry'
def Step1(numb):
    total1=0
    total2=0
    length=len(numb)
    for i in range(length-2,-1,-2):
        double=eval(numb[i])*2
        if double>9:
            doublex=str(double)
            doubleY=int(doublex[0])+int(doublex[1])
            total1+=doubleY
        else:
            total2+=double
        total=total1+total2
        return total        
def Step2(numb):
    total=0
    length=len(numb)
    for i in range(length-1,-2,-2):
        total+=i
    return total
def Step3(num1,num2):
    total=num1+num2
    if total%10==0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
def main():
    inFile=open('pa7.cards','r')
    cardNum=inFile.readline().strip()
    while cardNum!='99999':
        step1=Step1(cardNum)
        step2=Step2(cardNum)
        step3=Step3(step1,step2)
        print(step1)
        print(step2)
        print(step3)
        cardNum=inFile.readline().strip()
    inFile.close()
main()
```

This is the data file:

```
4388576018402626 
4388576018410707 
37271983
5190828258102121
99999
```

This is the output i am getting when printing all 3 steps

```
4
63
False
0
63
False
7
15
False
4
63
False
```

Comment: `numb[0:1]` gives only one char - it has to be `numb[0:2]`

Comment: oh, thanks for noticing that, but the outputs are still all coming up false for step3

Comment: Add more `print()` to see what values you have in variables

Comment: i just don't see what's going wrong in the code, step 1 and step 2 functions dont seem to be working properly

Comment: What's your expected output from step1 and step 2?

Comment: i believe step 1 shoulld be 37 and step 2 should be 38, both adding up to be 75 for the first credit card number,

Comment: could your problem be in the `eval` function? you're passing strings, and eval applied against a string like `eval('3')*2` will yield result of `33`, not `6`.  Try `int(num[1]) * 2` instead.

Comment: You have `def Step1()`'s `return total` statement inside the `for` loop, so the loop will never finish. Is that in your code, or a typo in your question?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I noticed that too, looks like typo

Comment: oh, wow, yeah i never noticed that, ok so the first step is fixed now it gives me all of the correct results, though the second step still doesn't work

Comment: Use `int` and put your code through the a step-by-step debugger. Like here: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit  Pretty sure this will help you solve it.

Comment: Luhn algoritm Step 2 is "*take the sum of all the digits*" but your Step 2 function doesn't do that, it does `for i in range(length-1,-2,-2): total+=i` - I imagine it should be `for i in range(length-1,-1,-1): total+=numb[i]`  counting  minus one at a time instead of minus two, and taking the digits not the counter.

Comment: You'll need to do `total+=int(numb[i])` to cast the string to int.

Comment: Ok finally got it to work, thank you all

Comment: I've reposted my comments as a full answer, including @DavidZemens suggestions/corrections. Not sure how fair that is, but I wanted to write more suggestions too.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler that's fine by me, I see your answer now and i would agree with all of the same recommendations.

Comment: This is a great use case for unit tests. You could write code to call each function with data you already know the answer to. Get the parts working and then worry about the whole.

Answer (score 4):

(My comments as an answer, including suggestions and corrections from @DavidZemens' comments)

In terms of bugs, I think you have:

**Step 1** has the `return` statement inside the loop, so the loop only happens once, then it stops.

```
def Step1(numb):

    for i in range(length-2,-1,-2):

        return total     
    ^ --  ^ -- move this left, to where 'for' is
```

**Step 2** is adding up the counter, not the credit card digits, and it's stepping through *every other* digit instead of every digit:

```
def Step2(numb):
    total=0
    length=len(numb)

    for i in range(length-1,-1,-1):
        total += int(numb[i])

    return total
```

---

In general code comments, this kind of test:

```
if len(numb)>12 and len(numb)<17:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

is a bit redundant. *If (truth test) return True else return False* can become *return (truth test)*:

```
return 12 < len(numb) < 17
```

and later:

```
total = num1 + num2
if total%10==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be:

```
return (num1 + num2) % 10 == 0
```

---

This calculation:

```
    double=eval(numb[i])*2
    if double>9:
        doublex=str(double)
        doubleY=int(doublex[0])+int(doublex[1])
        total1 += doubleY
```

is a bit awkward turning the number into text, taking text characters, turning them back into numbers, then adding them up.

What it does is take the number of tens (integer divide by 10) and the remainder (modulo 10), so you could keep it all as numbers with:

```
double = int(numb[i]) * 2
if double > 9:
    total1 += (double // 10) + (double % 10)
```

---

`eval()` is a bad practice, it gives any input complete access to the Python interpreter with no safeguards. In your code, you could use `int()` instead

---

Your file loop could be clearer:

```
def main():
    with open('pa7.cards') as inFile:
        for cardNum in inFile:
            cardNum = cardNum.strip()
            step1=Step1(cardNum)
            step2=Step2(cardNum)
            step3=Step3(step1,step2)
            print(step1)
            print(step2)
            print(step3)
```

---

And you might get some benefit by converting the cardNum into a list of numbers once and then working with that, instead of calling `int()` all over the place.

You can also optimize the two unused functions (assuming you use them elsewhere in the code):

```
def CheckLength(numb):
    return 12 < len(numb) < 17

def CheckType(numb):
    """ 
    returns the type of credit card, based on the first digit or 2 digits
    numb; passed as string
    """
    n = numb[0] if not numb[0] == '3' else numb[:1]
    d = {4:'Visa',
         5:'Mastercard',
         6:'Discover',
         37:'American Express'}
    return d.get(int(n), 'Invalid Entry')
```

Comment: @DavidZemens - in your edit, CheckLength isn't checking the length, and in CheckType you're converting the entire credit card number into an integer and expecting it to come out as 4,5,6 or 7 instead of testing the first one or two digits (which I think means it can't be a single dictionary lookup)? Neither of those look quite right.

Comment: My mistake, I had started working on those functions before I saw that they weren't even used in the rest of the code, I think they were unfinished, but I made some add'l changes.